# Visual Studio 2017 default reference documentation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

It looks like Visual Studio 2017 switched its online reference documentation from .Net Framework to .Net Core: every time I hit the `F1` key, I get sent on .Net Core documentation for the type/method on which the caret was.

Very well if I were in a .Net .Core project, but it does it too on .Net Framework 4.6.1 projects. And on this .Net Core help, there is no *Show other versions* drop down list. (Which is understandable, that is not really a newer version of .Net Framework 4.x.)
This renders this key almost useless to me. I end up googling the type / method for getting the MSDN .Net Framework 4.x documentation. (Which is currently more complete for subjects existing in both, compare [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1#System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentBag_1_System_Collections_IEnumerable_GetEnumerator) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381960(v=vs.110).aspx).)

Is there any way to get the `F1` key to open from Visual Studio 2017 the .Net Framework 4.x documentation for the type/method on which the caret is?

I have found no settings for that neither in Help nor in Tools/Options.

This issue affects only online help. Technically Visual Studio does not seem to be blamed. It launches the browser on a MSDN website url with parameters specifying the framework and its version. But MSDN redirects regardless to .Net Core documentation. So it now appears to me as a MSDN website bug.

Example url on which Visual Studio 2017 sends:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true
```

Resulting MSDN redirection: 301 => `https://msdn...` then 302 =>

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.runtime.serialization.streamingcontext
```

While Visual Studio 2015 sends on:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true
```

Which only redirects to the https version of the url, then serves the page.

Comment: It's the same for me, but it works if I let the help launch in the Help Viewer

Comment: Thanks. Installing the feature "Help viewer" for Visual Studio gave me that choice, and moreover from the local help a working link to web version is available. So it is a good workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now this has changed.

As already stated in my question edit, that is more a documentation web site trouble than a Visual Studio trouble.

Moreover, the learn.microsoft.com web site has now changed its redirection. For the provided example, it now gets redirected to (no more `core` in the path):

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.streamingcontext
```

Which redirects further to:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.streamingcontext?view=netframework-4.7
```

Well, still not the asked framework (4.7 instead of 4.6.1), but way better than landing on .Net Core documentation instead of .Net Framework.

It also looks as complete as msdn documentation, though not giving the option to see documentation for versions prior to 4.5.

And indeed in my few tests, changing the version does not seem to reload the page, it seems a bit cosmetic for now... In fact, that is the Core reference documentation which is now gone!

So that move from msdn to docs looks like a bit premature, the learn.microsoft.com site seems to be still a "work in progress" site.

Anyway, it does not look to me there is anything to do on Visual Studio 2017 side. Just wait for the new documentation site to get finished.